# How can i insert particular comment on particular post? (for eg. facebook) in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i insert particular comment on particular post? (like Facebook)
i have two table in sql

1. wall=>wallid, username,post
2. post comment=>wall id,comment,comment id

when i insert wall id manually, it works fine, but i want that the wall id should be generated automatically to the post i enter comment in.

In design part

```
<div style="text-align: center">

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="61px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="271px"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="37px" Text="Submit" Width="91px" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

    </div>
    <div>
        <br />
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="border: solid 2px brown; width: 400px; margin-bottom: 20px">
                    <span style="">Id:
                <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("wallId") %>' />
                        <br />
                        post:
                <asp:Label ID="postLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("post") %>' />
                        <br />
                        username:
                <asp:Label ID="usernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </span>
                    <br />
                    <hr style="height: 3px; background-color: blue" />

                    <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataKeyNames="commentID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
                        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            <span style="">commentID:<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("commentID") %>' runat="server" ID="commentIDLabel" />
                                <br />
                                wallID:<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("wallID") %>' runat="server" ID="wallIDLabel" />
                                <br />
                                comment:<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("comment") %>' runat="server" ID="commentLabel" />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <hr style="height: 3px; background-color: blue" />
                        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <span style="">commentID:<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("commentID") %>' runat="server" ID="commentIDLabel1" />
                                <br />
                                wallID:<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("wallID") %>' runat="server" ID="wallIDTextBox" />
                                <br />
                                comment:<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("comment") %>' runat="server" ID="commentTextBox" />
                                <br />
                                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" ID="UpdateButton" /><asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" ID="CancelButton" /><br />
                                <br />
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <hr style="height: 3px; background-color: blue" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <span>No data was returned.</span>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <span style="">wallID:<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("wallID") %>' runat="server" ID="wallIDTextBox" />
                                <br />
                                comment:<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("comment") %>' runat="server" ID="commentTextBox" />
                                <br />
                                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ID="InsertButton" /><asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" ID="CancelButton" /><br />
                                <br />
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <hr style="height: 3px; background-color: blue" />
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <span style="">commentID:<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("commentID") %>' runat="server" ID="commentIDLabel" />
                                <br />
                                wallID:<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("wallID") %>' runat="server" ID="wallIDLabel" />
                                <br />
                                comment:<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("comment") %>' runat="server" ID="commentLabel" />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <hr style="height: 3px; background-color: blue" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer" style=""><span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" /></div>
                            <div style="">
                            </div>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <SelectedItemTemplate>
                            <span style="">commentID:<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("commentID") %>' runat="server" ID="commentIDLabel" />
                                <br />
                                wallID:<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("wallID") %>' runat="server" ID="wallIDLabel" />
                                <br />
                                comment:<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("comment") %>' runat="server" ID="commentLabel" />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <hr style="height: 3px; background-color: blue" />
                        </SelectedItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource2" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [postcomment]" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [postcomment] WHERE [commentID] = @original_commentID AND [wallID] = @original_wallID AND (([comment] = @original_comment) OR ([comment] IS NULL AND @original_comment IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [postcomment] ([wallID], [comment]) VALUES (@wallID, @comment)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [postcomment] SET [wallID] = @wallID, [comment] = @comment WHERE [commentID] = @original_commentID AND [wallID] = @original_wallID AND (([comment] = @original_comment) OR ([comment] IS NULL AND @original_comment IS NULL))">
                        <DeleteParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_commentID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_wallID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_comment" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        </DeleteParameters>
                        <InsertParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="wallID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="comment" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        </InsertParameters>
                        <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="wallID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="comment" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_commentID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_wallID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_comment" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        </UpdateParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [wall]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema should look like

```
1. Post -> PostId,WallId,PostedBy, Post,PostedDateTime
2. Comments -> CommentId,PostId,Comments,CommentedBy,CommentedDateTime
```

Relaationship between Post and Wall should be 1 Wall and Many Posts that is 1:M relationship, similary for the comments, 1:M.

### On Save

do the following:

1. Generate PostId automatically.
2. Send WallId from querystring or session or by any means you are identifying the friends wall. Similarly find out the current user id who owns  the post and save the post and its datetime.
3. On comments, while saving comments, get the postid, and your own user id and leave the comment id autoincremented.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the solution by coding?

Comment: Sorry you have to try for that... We cannot spoon fed here.

Answer (score 0):

make the parameter direction as InputOutput parameter.

```
        <asp:Parameter Name="wallID" Type="Int32" Direction="InputOutput"></asp:Parameter>
```

then you can use on Inserted event :

```
        protected void ListView_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
          var wallID =   e.Command.Parameters["@wallID"].Value ;
        }
```

since you want the wallid to be automatically inserted as identity  value. The you have to selected so that it you can grape it. try this

```
DECLARE @wallID AS INT = -1

INSERT INTO [postcomment] 
            ([comment]) 
VALUES      (@comment)
select @wallID =SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

also it is not the ListView_Inserted event, it is the SqlDataSource2_Inserted

Comment: i edited in <asp:SqlDataSource> inputOutput Parameter but when i created listbox2 OnItemInserted event then its not showing any e.command option. can you please demonstrate my query in detail?